# QtCreator refuses to remember target device

Tags: android, qt-creator

When trying to compile android application in QtCreator, I'm first asked to select target device. I select it and check *Allways use this device...*
[image: image description]

However, next time I want to compile and run the program, this dialog pops up again. Can I change some setting so that it actually respects my *Allways use* setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was a bug and is now fixed.](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15422) Downloading [QtCreator directly from the master branch](http://ftp.fau.de/qtproject/snapshots/qtcreator/master/) contains the fix.